# batch scripting

Tags: cmd

How to print the output of a batch script to the email client.

Answer (score 2):

To display the output of a batch script (or any command) in notepad, in which you can easily copy and paste, you might type this in the command prompt:

```
your_batch_script.bat > tmpfile && (notepad tmpfile && pause && del tmpfile)
```

(the temporary file that is shown in notepad would disappear when you press any key back in the command prompt).

Answer (score 1):

Not sure that I understand your needs, but you can use blat command-line utility for Windows to send email using SMTP (http://www.blat.net/).

```
blat -to to_email -f from_email -server smtp_server -body body_text -s subject_text -attacht att_file
```

Answer (score 0):

If you could use cygwin or linux you may sendmail it:

echo -ne "Subject:test \n\n`cat $file` " | sendmail mailTObeUSED@

Answer (score 0):

To copy from `cmd.exe`:

1. Right click the title bar.
2. Choose "Mark".
3. Select a rectangle with the mouse by holding the LMB at one corner and raising the LMB at the opposite corner.
4. Right-click (RMB) to copy to the clipboard.

To write the output of a command to a file:

1. Run `mycommand.bat > filename.txt`.
   **Warning**: If filename.txt exists, it will be overwritten!
2. Open the newly created filename.txt.